# A bash script to concatenate strings and editing a line in the same file using a bash script

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, gnu-screen

I was trying to write a bash script to run several cases where the steps are the following:

1. reading a `.txt` file in an array
2. concatenate each element of an array with a specific string
3. opening several screens in detached mode and then changing a specific file
   (in this case `seq.txt`) and run a few commands

The code is as follows:

```
COUNTER=0
readarray t1Gad < t1_gad.txt
while [  $COUNTER -lt 5 ]; do
    NUM_DEVICE=8
    DEVICE_NO=`expr $COUNTER % $NUM_DEVICE`
    string1='objGa_'
    string2=${t1Gad[$COUNTER]}
    #string2='hello'
    string=$string1$string2
    echo $string2
    echo $string1
    echo $string
    screen -d -m -S "$COUNTER" bash -c 'cd $HOME/Downloads && sed -i '2s/.*/$string/' seq.txt && cat seq.txt; exec sh'
    let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
done
```

The funny thing is that if I replace `string2` with a fixed string, it is working fine, but it is not working with array elements of the array.

I would be happy if someone explains it to me. I am very new to bash scripting but desperately want to learn this very useful but ugly scripting language.

I found the problem but I do not know how to solve it. While doing the string concatenation, say e.g.

```
    string1="objGa_"
string="$string1${t1Gad[$COUNTER]}"
```

(say 192 is that specific element)and in that case it is substituting

```
objGa_192 ' '
```

inside the screen. I do not know how to get rid of that space and where it is coming from.

t1_gad.txt:

```
100
200
300
400
500
```

seq.txt:

```
abc
objw
cde
efg
xyz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readarray` places a whitespace at end of each variable, which seems to be causing problems with the `sed` command.

One elegant way get rid of a trailng whitespace is to pipe the string to `xargs`:

```bash
string2=$(echo ${t1Gad[$COUNTER]} | xargs)
```

Comment: No... none of solutions are working .... the .txt file is like acolumn with no space between in each column... and I saw somewhere 2s stands for editing 2nd line...in sed

Comment: Could you include `t1_gad.txt` and `seq.txt` in your question?

Comment: I added the .txt files in the question.

Comment: I changed my answer to something that worked for me (I have the old one saved in a text file).